# Python shell window in compiled applet

Tags: python, shell, applet, compiled

I am trying to make an executable python program on MAC OSX. I used the build applet program and it runs, but I had some data printing in the shell window and the executable file does not open a window. Is there a way to open a shell window with an executable python program?

Thanks

Comment: when you say "compiled" and "applet" are you referring to using Automator to make an app around your python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Automator to simply run your python script, and you really need it to open a shell window, here is a cheap hack:

Using a simple application with Run Shell Script action:

```
open -a Terminal /path/to/python/script.py
```

But if all your application is doing is printing output, all that output would be visible in the Console.app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about generating another shell window, but do you need to have an entire shell open? What about getting the information to the user in a different way, such as:

- use another Toplevel window and insert the output into a Text or Listbox, rather than simply printing it.  This could also make it easier for users to copy the output (if that's something they might find useful).
- write out a data/log file.